# How to create a floating label entry in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I decided to create a control that will work like Android's floating label entry (for it to work with both, Android and iOS). The way to go for me seemed to create a view that will have two items, Entry and Label. On `Entry.Focused` event I'll animate the label to move upward. On `Entry.Unfocused` event, if there'll be any text, nothing will change, if the entry will be empty, I'll reverse the animation. Now, the problem is that I don't want to inherit from `View`, because I want my view to have all the properties that `Entry` has and I don't want to implement all of them by myself. The best way seems to be inheriting from Entry and adding custom functionality, but in this case, I don't know how to overlay a `Label` over the entry. My question is, how do I do that? How do I extend `Entry` so that I'll be able to overlay it with some other items?

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, please ask for more info if something is unclear and I'll elaborate.

Comment: sorry bro see this link not above...https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField

Comment: my project is in Xamarin Forms

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code? For Overlay you can use Relative or Absolute layout.

Comment: I can create this item using layouts, however I want the element to be reusable and I don't want to copy layout and animation code every time I need an entry. What can I try, though? That's the point, I'm not asking about the code, I'm asking, which path should I take?

Comment: If you want to do in the forms you can do it as a custom control, you don't need to copy it everywhere. Just expose enough properties and wire it up.

Comment: Syncfusion has released a new control called [SfTextInputLayout](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/text-input-layout). It helps to achieve your requirement in Xamarin.Forms. Also If you are eligible for Syncfusion community license, you can use all their products for free.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is on the old side, but for anyone who has the same question, there's a library that can do this for you called `PhantomLib`. It's an open source nuget package that has a bunch of features like adding a show/hide button to an entry for passwords, adding an `X` button to an entry for clearing the text, floating label entry, and much more. [Here's](https://www.ostusa.com/blog/customize-xamarin-forms-open-source-code/) a blog post on how to use it  and the library is located [here](https://github.com/OSTUSA/PhantomLib).